# Создание клиент-серверного приложения

Tags: c++, клиент-сервер

Нужно создать простое клиент-серверное приложение на **C++/MFC**.

**Сервер должен** отслеживать изменения в указанной папке на локальном диске и вести журнал изменений.

**Клиент должен**:

- реагировать на изменения в журнале сервера и выводить данные пользователю
- при запуске нескольких экземпляров клиентов, каждый экземпляр должен получать все записи журнала.

Подскажите литературу и туториалы.
Вот что я нашел:

- [Ссылка 1](http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-cli/thread641855.html)
- [Ссылка 2](http://www.programmersforum.ru/showthread.php?t=214762)
- [Ссылка 3](http://www.vr-online.ru/content/setevoe-programmirovanie-chast-3-klient-server-4356)
- [Ссылка 4](http://club.shelek.ru/viewart.php?id=325)

И вообще это сильно сложно сделать? За неделю можно осилить, если раньше не создавал клиент-серверные приложения? Это тестовое задание, поэтому нужно максимально простое приложение.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738545(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В качестве простейшего client-server приложения можно взять пример из чудесного мануала Криса Касперского "Самоучитель игры на WinSock".

> kpnc.opennet.ru/sock.pdf

После чего наращивать разобранную базу.

С уважением maxspb.